# REST/JSON webapp - java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2560

Tags: java, tomcat, lambda, jersey, java-stream

I am getting the following exception in a REST/JSON web-app in Apache Tomcat when I use stream / lambda functions. I am puzzled as to why this is happening.

### Environment

- Windows 7
- Oracle JDK 1.8.0_25
- Tomcat 7.0.62
- The code was compiled using java version "1.8.0_65" (Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17), Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)) on Ubuntu
- Jackson 1.9.2 and Jersey 1.17.1

### Possible Root Cause

I have found that commenting out the following code avoids the issue. But when I put the code back in, I never see any log statements. My `try{}catch{}` seems pointless.

```
public static Statistics get(PolicyFile mainPolicy, List<PolicyFile> referencePolicies) throws Exception {
    try {
        Stream<BuildingBlock> matchingResults = mainPolicy.getBuildingBlocks().stream();
        long ruleCount = matchingResults.filter(b -> "Rule".equals(b.getType())).count();
        long policyCount = matchingResults.filter(b -> "Policy".equals(b.getType())).count();
        long policysetCount = matchingResults.filter(b -> "PolicySet".equals(b.getType())).count();
        long permitCount = matchingResults.filter(b -> b.getDecision()!=null && Result.DECISION_PERMIT==b.getDecision()).count();
        long denyCount = matchingResults.filter(b -> b.getDecision()!=null && Result.DECISION_DENY==b.getDecision()).count();
        return new Statistics(ruleCount, policyCount, policysetCount, permitCount, denyCount);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Cannot parse data", e);
    }
}
```

### Stack trace

```
May 30, 2017 12:05:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2560
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.JarFileScanner.scan(JarFileScanner.java:97)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.JarZipSchemeScanner$1.f(JarZipSchemeScanner.java:78)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.JarZipSchemeScanner.scan(JarZipSchemeScanner.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:225)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:141)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:696)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

May 30, 2017 12:05:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet jersey-servlet
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2560
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.JarFileScanner.scan(JarFileScanner.java:97)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.JarZipSchemeScanner$1.f(JarZipSchemeScanner.java:78)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.JarZipSchemeScanner.scan(JarZipSchemeScanner.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:225)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:141)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:696)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

May 30, 2017 12:05:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2560
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.JarFileScanner.scan(JarFileScanner.java:97)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.JarZipSchemeScanner$1.f(JarZipSchemeScanner.java:78)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.JarZipSchemeScanner.scan(JarZipSchemeScanner.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:225)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:141)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:696)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

May 30, 2017 12:05:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet jersey-servlet
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2560
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:136)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.JarFileScanner.scan(JarFileScanner.java:97)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.JarZipSchemeScanner$1.f(JarZipSchemeScanner.java:78)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.JarZipSchemeScanner.scan(JarZipSchemeScanner.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:225)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:141)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:696)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```